# Is it possible to freeze group headers in tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

My issue is that group headers are scrolled away when I scroll vertically. I need them to stay frozen just like the 'freeze row' option. I couldn't find a way to get the row object of group header, with which I can use the freeze option.

Please guide me in the right direction.

JS Code:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    movableRows:true,
    groupBy:"gender",
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", formatter:"progress", sorter:"number"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"Rating", field:"rating", formatter:"star", hozAlign:"center", width:100},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", hozAlign:"center", sorter:"date"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", hozAlign:"center", formatter:"tickCross"},
    ],
});
```

HTML Code

```html
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: please, add your code for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `position: sticky` css on group header class `.tabulator-row.tabulator-group` with a higher `z-index`

```css
.tabulator-row.tabulator-group {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.tabulator-row.tabulator-group:hover {
  background: #eaeaea; /* Default hover background has an opacity: rgba(0,0,0,.1) */
}
```

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/izmirli/pen/zYPVBxq

**Edit**

Note: Also need to set `renderVerticalBuffer` option to a number higher than the expected row count in Tabulator settings for this to work properly. However, this may cause performance issues with large data sets.

Comment: This appraoch wont work for tables with more than a few rows. Because Tabulator uses a Virtual DOM only the visible rows actually exist (plus a view outside the table viewport). all other rows are created and destroyed as you scroll. so while the groups may stick at the top, as you scroll the will be destroyed by the virtual DOM

Comment: Thanks for the info Oli!  I do something similar in one of my applications but I do have the `renderVerticalBuffer` set to a high number which works well for me.  I will update the answer in case someone wants to try it out but I understand it may not work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible im afraid.

Tabulator group headers are loaded into the table with the same priority as rows so they all scroll togeather.